# Selectively using 'grep --after-context' on one term but not another

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, grep

I'm pulling in loads of data from a network and filtering for `foo` and `bar`, e.g.

```
for i in example.com example.org example.net
do
     echo "Data from $i"
     curl $i/data.csv | grep --after-context=3 "foo|bar"
done
```

Every time `foo` appears, I need to see the next few lines (`grep --after-context=3`), but when `bar` appears, I only need that single line.

Is it possible to make it work in a single `grep`, `sed`, `awk` (or other standard unix) command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
curl .... | awk  '/foo/{x=NR+3}(NR<=x) || /bar/'
```

When foo is encountered, x is set to current line number + 3, and hence the condition `(NR+x)` makes the line "foo" and the next 3 lines get printed. `/bar/` makes the line containing the `bar` printed.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Now on to nesting if's :)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN {np=0} /bar/ {print; next} /foo/ {np=1;ln=RN;print;next} ln!=0 && RN>(ln+3) {np=0;ln=0} np==1 {print}' INPUTFILE
```

Instead of the `grep`, you might use the above. What it does:

1. in `BEGIN` sets up the non printing variable.
2. `/bar/ {print}` if you can't figure this out, well... (the `next` is for skipping every other rules and move to the next record).
3. `/foo/ {np=1;ln=RN;print}` prints `foo` lines, saves the line number, and sets print later lines
4. if the actual row number is greater than the saved line number plus 3, sets printing to off
5. if we need to print (`np>0`), then print.

Comment: I marked Guru's answer as the "right" one because it was simple, not because yours wasn't useful - thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed -n '/foo/,+3{p;b};/bar/p' file
```